# How accurate is a MPU9250 IMU for direction and velocity measurement?

Tags: localization

Pardon the intrusion I've posted this on the Raspberry Pi stack, but I wonder if I might find an answer here more quickly.

I'm currently experimenting with a MPU9250 Inertial Measurement Unit (gyroscope, magnetometer & accelerometer) mounted on a three wheeled car chassis, with two motors. I have mounted the MPU on a breadboard as far as I can from the magnets in the motors, which might throw out the IMU's magnetometer.

I don't need to locate the car's position exactly, but I do need its velocity in the X Y plane (especially heading and to a less extent magnitude). I can, no doubt, find the necessary calculations on line to approximate the velocity but what I'm not clear on is how accurate a MPU9250 will be. I have seen a figure in location error of 150m per minute in a paper from 2007, but nothing more recent referring to velocity.

Can someone point me in a suitable direction (no pun intended) ?

TIA